# Usage of the word 'Each'

Tags: grammar, word-usage

I saw the following sentence in a journal paper.

> The base stations, users, and relays are each equipped with one antenna.

I'm sure it means that each of them is equipped with one antenna.
However, I can't understand how the word 'each' is placed there in the sentence above.
I've learned that 'each' acts as a determiner or a pronoun depending on the sentence.
Hence, as far as I am concerned, it should be written as

> Each of the base stations, users, and relays is equipped with one antenna.

or

> The base stations, users, and relays are equipped with one antenna, respectively.

However, I've seen the structure of the first sentence several times.
Accordingly, I felt there is a sentence structure or grammar that I don't know.
Please explain how 'each' can be placed between be verb and past participle.

Comment: [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/each) says that *each* can also be an adverb. And it's certainly acting very much like one here.

Comment: "Each" is certainly not an adverb. It's a determinative in a fused-head noun phrase, where it is functioning as a quantificational adjunct in clause structure, see here: [link](https://simple.wiktionary.org/wiki/each)

Comment: Do they mean "user workstations" or "user devices"? The idea of people each being equipped with an antenna like 1950s drawings of aliens seems bizarre.

Comment: @BoldBen They mean user devices.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The entry on *each* in *Collins Cobuild English Usage* (p204) notes in the section *'used after subject'*:

> *Each* is sometimes used after the subject of the clause, For example, instead of saying *'Each of them received a new pairs of boots'*, you
> can say *'They each received a new pair of boots'*.

The CCEU then goes on to state:

> This type of construction is often used to indicate that an amount
> relates to each member of a group separately and not to the whole
> group.

The CCEU entry concludes by saying:

> When you are talking about an amount like this, you often put *each* at
> the end of the clause.

So, an alternative to the sentence you quote is:

> The base stations, users, and relays are equipped with one antenna
> each.

Comment: Thank you. I understood your answer, and the last one is also acceptable for me. This is rather familiar than others. By the way, according to the comment "used after subject", do I have to use as follows instead of the first sentence (... are each equipped ...) in my question? "The base stations, users, and relays each is equipped with one antenna."

Comment: @Danny_Kim. Swan in the entry on _each_ in _Practical English Usage_ (page 170) says: "When _each_ refers to the subject, it can also go with a verb in mid-position like some adverbs." Swan gives several examples, including: _You are each right in a different way._ This is equivalent to _they are each equipped..._. (Note that you need to use the plural _are_). Putting _each_ before _are_ does not sound so natural with the long subject of your sentence.

Answer (score 1):

*Each* (pronoun) acts as a distributive pronoun, i.e. almost adverbially with the meaning "individually"

OED:

> Each (pron.)
>
> **B 2. Used so as to indicate distribution of a plurality of things among the members of a set.**

> **a. Distributing a plural subject or object (e.g. the labourers will each receive a reward)**.
>
> OE   West Saxon Gospels: Matt. (Corpus Cambr.) xx. 9   *Þa onfengon hig **ælc** his pening. [then **each** received his penny]*
>
> 1945   Times 13 Feb. 4/1   *The forces of the three Powers will each occupy a separate zone of Germany.*
>
> 2004   S. Rothstein Predicates & Their Subj. x. 313   *Four farmers have each built a fence.*

Comment: This is the right answer. Let me note that other pronouns can come between the auxiliary verb and the verb — *he was himself equipped with a camera.*

Answer (score 1):

> *The base stations, users, and relays are each equipped with one*
> *antenna.*

"Each" is not a pronoun, despite what some people (and most dictionaries) claim. It actually belongs to the word class (part of speech) determinative.

It is separable and not part of the subject NP but a quantificational adjunct in clause structure. The adjunct has the form of a fused-head NP.

We know that this "each" is an adjunct because when the verb is an auxiliary, it preferentially follows rather then precedes it, as it does in your example.

Note that the same applies to the determinatives "all" and "both".

Source: CGEL (Huddleston & Pullum) p428